# What degree of punishment is assigned to one who wants to commit a sin, but is only stopped by the lack of an opportunity?

Tags: halacha, sin, reward-punishment, intent-accident-purposely

For instance, if one thought of murdering a certain someone, but the only thing stopping him was the lack of an opportunity, would he be liable to a punishment equal to that of a murderer, or something lesser? Is there no punishment at all?

Is there a difference between an individual who would commit the sin of his thoughts versus one who wouldn't?

This question came to mind after the subject of freedom of choice came up on Shabbat at the synagogue. If someone were to wish, like Hitler, that they could wipe out all the Jews, but the only thing stopping them is a lack of opportunity, would their punishment be equal to his (whatever it is)?

Comment: מחשבה רעה אין הקדוש ברוך הוא מצרפה למעשה ~[Kiddushin 40](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=40&format=pdf)

Comment: @Shokhet I can read Hebrew and I understand the title of the link for the most part, but I'd have some trouble understanding a whole page of it unfortunately.  (edit - thanks for the additon of the reference)

Comment: Some people are able to act on their intentions; others, when the moment to act comes, suddenly find a desire to give up their evil intentions. Are the latter part of your question?

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer `:)` (*also, it's not Hebrew -- it's more Aramaic*) ...basically, the idea is that even though God rewards people for thoughts related to good acts, He does not do the same for bad thoughts.

Comment: I don't understand your (current) second paragraph

Comment: @Shokhet Someone could think of murdering an individual, but they wouldn't actually do it versus someone who very much wants to do it, but lacks the opportunity. Both of them thought about it, neither of them did it, but only one of them truly wants to do it.

Comment: The first one I would dismiss as nonsense -- don't we all idly wonder what it would be like to walk off with someone else's car etc? ...the second, I think, is more the topic of the specific piece of Talmud that I cited, above

Comment: @Shokhet the gemara there explicitly says he is mitzaref machshava kimaase by nonjews, which the op is apparently talking about.

Comment: @user6591 Not reading the whole gemara through is another reason I posted a comment, and not an answer :) thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: FYI, several of the *Al Chet* recited on Yom Kippur relate specifically to evil and incorrect thoughts. There may not be direct punishment, but it may be a form of "related" punishment, as in general, you should not have incorrect thoughts.

Comment: related: [Are thoughts of sin punished halachically?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/are-thoughts-of-sin-punished-halachically)