# Are thoughts of sin punished halachically?

Tags: halacha, sin, reward-punishment

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68062/gay-people-in-the-torah-talmud-kabbalah), I got interested in the question of halakhic punishment for **thoughts of sin**?

In general, the Torah is not so concerned and doesn't judge how people feel or what their desires are. It is mainly concerned in how we act.

**On one side**

- the gmara in Kiddushin 40a explicitly says that Hashem doesn’t regard a bad thought that doesn’t lead to action as an action (artscroll comments “hence there is no punishment for the thought”)
- another gmara (end of Bava Batra 164b) says all men think of sin every single day (presumably meaning it is not punishable)

**On the other side**

- later in Kiddushin 40a the gmara says that thoughts of sins one has performed and now considers permitted are punished
- in Shabbat 64a we see the army returning from the war in Midian offered a korban to atone against their lustful thoughts
- R Chaim mi Volozhin writes (Nefesh HaChaim, gate 1, ch. 4) that the body is like a mishkan, the mind is the kodesh hakodashim and thinking unclean thoughts is a desecration even greater than defiling the Kodesh Hakodoshim since the Mishkan is physical and the mind is even more holy and spiritual

**So how is the halakha judging thoughts of sin?** Are specific halakhic works codifying this (as opposed to more philosophical discussions)?

Comment: related but not similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64044/what-degree-of-punishment-is-assigned-to-one-who-wants-to-commit-a-sin-but-is-o and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23391/dreaming-of-doing-a-sin

Comment: according to the Schottenstein (page 412) the Ibn Ezra talks about related issues when discussing Lo Tachmod.

Comment: sorry -- I meant the Stone chumash. This is what happens when I try to multi task. Headslap.

Comment: There's the halachic aspect of a person needing *kapara* (via *korban*) as shown [here](http://din.org.il/2014/02/21/%D7%92%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94/) according to several sources. There's also a distinction discussed there between a "quick thought" vs serious contemplation, etc.

Comment: In accordance with the Baal hatanye  it is  a sin to think wrong but the fault needs to be fixed. Because it stays a stain  . But there is no punishment because there is no maseh. But there is a letter from Reb Yankele from pshvorske that you can't be punished for thought.

Comment: @Cauthon thanks for this. Yes "quick thoughts" are fine, I thought [this](https://guardyoureyes.com/articles/prevention/item/do-thoughts-really-count) was a quite interesting discussion of this very topic

Comment: [Yoma 29a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=29&format=pdf)

Comment: Seems self-evident to me: thoughts of sin that are resisted are sources of reward for fighting temptation. One did not perform a prohibition, thus "fulfilling" it. Thoughts of sin that are not acted upon due to lack of opportunity or social pressure or whatever are spiritual flaws with no offsetting merit.

Comment: @MichaBerger thanks and I don't disagree but it is not that self-evident. Are thoughts forbidden in halacha and where? For instance thoughts of avoda zara are forbidden in some cases, thoughts of an aveira which one has done thus considers "more authorized" are forbidden, thoughts of Torah in the bathroom are forbidden (I know - not a sin). Maybe there are more. So despite the fact we say Torah is mostly concerned about actions, what are the parameters of forbidden thoughts?

Comment: see also end of Chulin 142a

Comment: See R David Bashevkin's Sin-a-gogue, p. 29, re Maharal's distinction (in Kidushin 39b) between sin which require action and can't be punished and sin where the forbidden thought is the action

Comment: Great article here - https://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/14-04-06/

Answer (score 7):

The Gemara in Masechet Yoma (29A) says:

> הרהורי עבירה קשין מעבירה וסימניך ריחא דבישרא 
>   (Thoughts of sin are harder than sin itself, as smell of meat is more attractive than taste of meat)

According to Rashi, the text addresses the physical harm caused by sexual desire, i.e. thinking of prohibited women (sexual thinking), compared with the physical harm caused by prohibited sexual intercourse:

> תאות נשים קשים להכחיש את בשרו יותר מגופו של מעשה

According to the Rabenu Bechaye (Cad Hakemach, [Taharat Halev](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41684&st=&pgnum=209)), there are many explanations for the Gemara's statement:

1. The first opinion: Thought is the most **spiritual** thing in man, and to impair or soil it is worse than to impair or soil the **material** body.
2. The second opinion: It is more difficult to overcome the impulse to sin caused by repetitive thought patterns than the impulse to sin caused by past physical sins that were not accompanied by continual sinful thinking.
3. The third opinion: The Gemara is talking about premeditation. When a man premeditates a sin, he will make every effort to achieve his target, even if he needs to kill someone for this. While planning, he is willing to commit additional sins in order to facilitate his target sin.
4. The fourth opinion (attributed to Ramban): The Gemara is talking about sinful thoughts that persist even after the sin has been committed. It is more than a simple desire. He cited a passage from Gemara Kidushin 40B, based on which he says that idle thoughts might not be acted upon and are less significant than a decision to act. Action results from a decision, not just idle thoughts. In his opinion (against the third opinion), a man will not be punished merely because of thinking or desiring; thinking and desiring is not manageable, and thoughts are often egodystonic. Against this argument, Rabenu Bechaye argued the existence of 'proactive' thinking: A man can anticipate and get into the right conditions in which no bad thoughts will come. The choice to adequately prepare for well-oriented thinking is entirely free, and whoever doesn't create the right conditions for himself is liable to punishment.

It seems that **Rabenu Behaye chooses the first opinion**. (I've seen this in the past: [Rambam (**More Nevuchim III, 8**)](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14118&st=&pgnum=487). It is a wonderful passage in the book).
See also [Rabenu Yona](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52052&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=), who cites a Hazal linked to this topic. There are cases in which the intention to sin, even if the person's plan to sin is foiled, is considered as if the sin was actually committed (in this regard, Rabenu Bechaye also cited thinking about idol worship).

Comment: How do you know that להכחיש את בשרו? What sort of injury? | `And the thinking remain sain.`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your English. Perhaps you should edit this answer (and your other answers, as well) to include a version of it in your native language, then quickly rollback your edit. This way, other users here can check your revision history to figure out what you mean and perhaps (if they have the time) help you edit your answer into a fully understandable form of English.

Comment: @kouty Ok. I edited it a little for readability. I hope it is an improvement. (I tried to leave the content - and your interpretations of sources - intact as much as possible. I don't take responsibility for your interpretation of sources one way or the other :) ). Feel free to edit it further or rollback edits as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The gemara says if a person is used to doing a sin they are punished for the thought, apparently because there is nothing internal stopping them from realising their thought into action other than external circumstances.

According to Reb YL Bloch you are not obliged to purify your thoughts to the extent that no thought of sin enters your mind because this is un-natural and would prevent you from living a healthy existence.

The other schools of Mussar, notably Novahrdok, disagree.

Comment: Citing sources would improve your answers immensely.

Comment: Thanks for this - the first gemara is indeed the one I cited, it is in Kiddushin 40a

Comment: Rabeynu Bechaye in his book develop the topic. I find this in Cad Hakemach.
The name of the Key is Taharath Halev. (Rambam counters Ramban) if I find time perhaps it will be a response.