# Noachide and sin confusion

Tags: sexuality, noachide-laws

For a noahide, do sexual  thoights without actions or arousal constitute sins?

I’m confused about this as it is not clear whether the sexual sins are just forbidden relations or also include more than that.

Comment: Why would you think it would be? Even for a Jew?

Comment: related (duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/are-thoughts-of-sin-punished-halachically

Answer (score -2):

To the extent that those thoughts can be avoided, they are a sin. This applies to all people.

Comment: Source?........

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Could you [edit] to add how you know this?  Because people here don't know who you or I or anyone else are, it's best to support answers with sources or logic.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya R Dan. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note your answer goes against two statements in the gemara (see the question [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68094/are-thoughts-of-sin-punished-halachically) and its answers). Hope to see you around!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33892)

Comment: @sabbahillel How does this not provide an answer to the question?